# Is the visualvm graph jumping expected

Tags: visualvm

I really like visualVM and think it's a great tool. However, after running for about an hour the graphs (cpu, mem, and others) start jumping around and requires a restart. I suspect this has something to do with the app trying to sample the dataset because there is too much data to show on the graph.

I've searched the [issues list](http://java.net/jira/browse/VISUALVM) and don't see this listed. Given that's it's behaved like this for as long as I've used it and that [others are complaining about it](http://java.net/projects/visualvm/lists/dev/archive/2011-02/message/5), I'm wondering if it's intended behavior. I guess that's the first question.

The second would be, why is it keeping all the data points, why not throw the oldest point away when a new point arrives and the buffer is full?

Answer (score 0):

For the first question see this: http://java.net/projects/visualvm/lists/dev/archive/2011-02/message/7. 
For second question: VisualVM does not keep all the data points, it throws the oldest point away when a new point arrives and the buffer is full. How did you came to the conclusion, that keeps all data.